# how to merge into one object from different strings in useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I need to write in a value hook with different data from different text inputs

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState({
  title: '',
  url: '',
  description: '',
});

<View style={styles.input_container}>
  <TextInput
    onChangeText={text => handleChange(text)}
    value={value.title}
    placeholder="enter book title"
  />
  <TextInput
    onChangeText={text => handleChange(text)}
    value={value.url}
    placeholder="link to book"
  />

  <TextInput
    onChangeText={text => handleChange(text)}
    value={value.description}
    placeholder="description"
  />
  <Button title="add" onPress={pressHandler} />
</View>;
```

wrong handler

```js
const handleChange = val => {
  setValue({
    value: {
      title: val,
      url: val,
      description: val,
    },
  });
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is a solid usecase for `useReducer` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer, alternatively, you could create multiple `useState` variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use indication for which kind of key you are referring to:

```
const handleChange = ({ type, text }) =>
  setValue((prev) => ({ ...prev, [type]: text }));
```

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({
  title: "",
  url: "",
  description: "",
});

<View style={styles.input_container}>
  <TextInput
    onChangeText={(text) => handleChange({ type: `title`, text })}
    value={value.title}
    placeholder="enter book title"
  />
  <TextInput
    onChangeText={(text) => handleChange({ type: `url`, text })}
    value={value.url}
    placeholder="link to book"
  />

  <TextInput
    onChangeText={(text) => handleChange({ type: `description`, text })}
    value={value.description}
    placeholder="description"
  />
  <Button title="add" onPress={pressHandler} />
</View>;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `useState` hooks you can do this.

```js
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
const [description, setDescription] = useState('');

<
View style = {
    styles.input_container
  } >
  <
  TextInput
onChangeText = {
  text => setTitle(text)
}
value = {
  value.title
}
placeholder = "enter book title" /
  >
  <
  TextInput
onChangeText = {
  text => setUrl(text)
}
value = {
  value.url
}
placeholder = "link to book" /
  >

  <
  TextInput
onChangeText = {
  text => setDescription(text)
}
value = {
  value.description
}
placeholder = "description" /
  >
  <
  Button title = "add"
onPress = {
  pressHandler
}
/> < /
View >
```